# How to resolve AllocaInst from a Value that was a result of a LoadInst in LLVM?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm

Conceptually what I would like to do is pretty simple.  I am using the [Alloca technique described in the Kaleidoscope example](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl7.html#memory-in-llvm) paired with [mem2reg](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#mem2reg-promote-memory-to-register) to reduce the need to manually create Phi nodes.

I have implemented several aspects of my custom language, but I have ran into a problem with implementing post increment/decrement in a generic way.

My AST node `PostIncrDecrNode` contains a token to denote `++` or `--` and an expression AST node that is codegened to return an `llvm::Value*` much like the Kaleidoscope example.  I have already noticed that I will likely need to return something other then an `llvm::Value*` as my language is very type safe and I need to know things such as signedness of integral types, but now I feel that I may also need to keep track of the `llvm::AllocaInst`.

A simple example situation is code like this:

```
int myfunction(int i)
{
    return i++;
}
```

My debug AST print looks like this:

```
- CompilationUnit:test.str
    - FunctionDeclarationNode
        - IdentifierNode:int
        - IdentifierNode:myfunction
        - FunctionParameterNode
            - IdentifierNode:int
            - IdentifierNode:i
        - BlockNode
            - ReturnNode
                - PostIncrDecrNode
                    - IdentifierNode:i
```

The last two lines are the relevant part here as I have a `PostIncrDecrNode` that contains an `IdentifierNode` that will be codegened like this:

```
Value* IdentifierNode::codeGenInternal(CodeGenContext& context)
{
    Value* rtn = NULL;
    SharedSymbolEntry entry = context.getSymbolInScopeByName(*value);
    Value* val = entry ? entry->llvmVal : NULL;
    if(val)
    {
        IRBuilder<>* builder = context.getIRBuilder();
        rtn = builder->CreateLoad(val, value->c_str());
    }
    else
    {
        context.handleCodeGenError(*this, "Unknown variable name: " + Twine(value->c_str()));

    }
    return rtn;
}
```

The line `SharedSymbolEntry entry = context.getSymbolInScopeByName(*value);` uses the stored `shared_ptr` to `std::String` 'value' member of the `IdentifierNode` (aka the variable name) to look up my `SharedSymbolEntry` (just a wrapper type to store language specific information along with the `llvm::Value*` which is the `llvm::AllocaInst*`) in the context stack which is populated with entry block allocas by function parameters or variable AST nodes.

The problem is that the `PostIncrDecrNode` doesn't have access to the alloca, only the returned `llvm::Value*` from the load `rtn = builder->CreateLoad(val, value->c_str());`.

Is there any way in LLVM to resolve the `llvm::AllocaInst*` from the `llvm::Value*` in order to use it in a store instruction (the store instruction needs a pointer and I only have the integral value in this case)?

I ran into a few similar questions, but I'm not sure if they answer my question.
The last one seems to suggest that this may not be possible at all so I would be curious how others have solved this problem.

- [llvm-dependencies-alloca-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503561/llvm-dependencies-alloca-load)
- [llvm-pass-how-to-insert-a-variable-using-existing-variable-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325698/llvm-pass-how-to-insert-a-variable-using-existing-variable-value)
- [get-pointer-to-llvmvalue-previously-allocated-for-createload-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692984/get-pointer-to-llvmvalue-previously-allocated-for-createload-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are returning a `llvm::Value*` (in your case it is a `LoadInst*`) you can cast the `llvm:Value*` to `llvm::LoadInst*` using the the LLVM RTTI system like this:

```
Value* val = someFunction(...); 
if (llvm::LoadInst* I = dyn_cast<llvm::LoadInst>(val)
{
     // do something with the load instruction I
}
else // not a load instruction
```

When have your `llvm::LoadInst*` you can easily access the address where the load has happened with getPointerOperand(). 
Now you can try to cast the pointer operand back to an `AllocaInst*` as in the example above. If it succeeds you have your `AllocaInst`, when it failes it is something else (e.g. a `GetElementPtrInst`).

Comment: Thank you!  I will probably start with that approach.